# My .htaccess file rules not allowing all REQUEST_METHOD to execute

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, post, submit

I realized that my .htaccess rules below to remove PHP and HTML extensions from the URL are denying all posts on the server.

```
 #unless directory, removes the .php
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]

#unless directory, removes the .html
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.html
```

If I remove this rules, my posts are executed successfully but I don't want to use the file extensions.

Comment: Have you checked that your first redirection (`/page.php` -> `/page`) actually works with the GET method ? Because, as you don't use a fully qualified URL, Apache uses configuration variables (such as ServerName) to build the target URL ([doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r)), and if those are not configured correctly then the redirection will fail not only for POST requests but with GET as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I ask it to rewrite the condition only when the REQUEST_METHOD not POST it works perfectly.

```
## To remove php extension unless it is directory ##
RewriteBase /
##The magic line. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```